# Error de entrada/salida en Centos7

Tags: linux

Cuando intento ejecutar cualquier comando me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error de entrada/salida

Por ejemplo al ejecutar el comando `ll` (para ver los archivos y directorios dentro de un directorio) obtengo lo siguiente:

> ls: no se puede abrir el directorio .: Error de entrada/salida

Hacer notar que el sistema de archivos está lleno y es, precisamente, por ello que quería borrar algunos archivos, pero no me permite visualizar ninguno de ellos.

¿Alguna sugerencia para resolver ese error?, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deberías [iniciar Centos en modo de rescate](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Rescue_Mode/) a través de su opción de arranca (si la tiene) o bien a través del CD/USB de arranque. Te permite arrancar un sistema mínimo que no usa el disco duro local en el que puedes trabajar y también montar el sistema de archivos raíz o aquél con el que estés teniendo problemas. También puedes hacer uso de `systemctl rescue` si ya has arrancado el sistema de manera normal, aunque podría dar problemas el cambio de un modo a otro.

Comment: Gracias oscar. al ejecutar el dmesg obtengo lo siguiente: [4990146.873766] XFS (dm-2): Corruption of in-memory data detected.  Shutting down filesystem
[4990146.873906] XFS (dm-2): Please umount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s).

Comment: Con esas condiciones podría ejecutar el systemctl rescue?

Comment: Debes realizar la operación que te he sugerido y ejecutar `xfs_repair` sobre el sistema de archivos dañado. Quizá debas agregar también el modificador `-L` para que limpie el registro (por si está dañado). El error indica problemas en la consistencia de datos, ya sea porque el dispositivo donde se escribió está defectuoso, o porque se ha realizado una modificación del mismo por otro motivo.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo arrancar con un CD/USB de rescate. Es la opción más limpia y segura para trabajar con una máquina que tiene un sistema de archivos dañado (máxime si el sistema de archivos dañado es el raíz).

Comment: En mi caso se trata de un servidor virtul, ¿se podría solucionar a nivel de VMWare?

Comment: Para mayor comodidad, [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133117/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-bhuchanix).

Comment: Necesito al menos 20 de reputación para poder usar el chat, aún no alcanzo